# Dictionary equivalent to Config

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, configuration

I have a `.config` file which contains a couple of values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Element1" value="true"/>
    <add key="Element2" value="true"/>
    <add key="Element3" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I would like to write them to a `Dictionary` structure. Is there a way to do so?

What if I have more than one config file - how can I manage the relevant ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to Xml

```
var settings = XDocument.Load(path_to_config)
                        .Root.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
                        .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"),
                                      a => (string)a.Attribute("value"));
```

But note, that [`<appSettings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) element can also have `<remove>` and `<clear>` child elements. Which is not easy to treat. So, I'd go with usage of [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which gives you dictionary-like access to app settings:

```
string element2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Element2"];
```

Or even

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings; // NameValueCollection
string element3 = settings["Element3"];
```

Comment: @user3165438 I added link to MSDN - those elements affect result settings. E.g. if you will put `<clear/>` that will remove all previously specified settings.

Answer (score 2):

I guess here's what you need:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k]);
```